# Modifying ancestor nested Meta class in descendant

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have:

```
class A(object):

    class Meta:
        a = "a parameter"


class B(A):

    class Meta:
        a = "a parameter"
        b = "b parameter"
```

How can I avoid having to rewrite the whole Meta class, when I only want to append `b = "b parameter"` to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could subclass `A.Meta`:

```
class B(A):    
    class Meta(A.Meta):
        b = "b parameter"
```

Now `B.Meta` inherits all attributes from `A.Meta`, and all you have to do is declare overrides or new attributes.